# Interface not found error in laravel in live server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have laravel application. The application works in my local computer fine. But when I upload it to my hosting server its not working. its return 500 error like that
[image]

its create a file named **error_log** in root directory

Here I share the **error_log** file

> [28-Mar-2016 19:16:23 Asia/Dhaka] PHP Fatal error:  Interface
>   'Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container' not found in
>   /home/sahadat/public_html/school_admin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 16

**N.B.** I use shared hosting.

Comment: Well, bad news. You need to perform commands in order to get laravel running over a hosing server, when your hosting is shared generally you are not allowed to run commands for security reasons. Example, you need to run `composer install` to install dependency packages like `laravel` (the errors in your question comes because this package is not installed). Then, in every change you need to run `composer dump-autoload`. If you can run those commands, you are saved.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the solution but strongly believing that the issue of upgrading to laravel 5.2

Try this link, may be helpful.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/error-when-upgrading-to-52-class-log-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem this way. The folder

> vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/contracts

was not uploaded. I don't know why the folder was not uploaded. I upload the folder manually and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The first and easiest thing to do is to double-check the spelling and capitalization of the **class name**, **file name** and **namespace** both in the class definition and where it is used.